# Node JS module in Geth is not found

Tags: go-ethereum, nodejs, solc, compiler

I have installed solC module with command:

```
npm install solc
```

How can I use this module in Geth?

When I execute `var solc = require("solc")` in Geth's console, interpreter throws:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'solc'
at s (web3.js:1:160)
at s (web3.js:1:122)
at <anonymous>:1:12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will not use var `solc = require("solc")` in `geth` but in `nodejs`.
for example, creat a test.js file and copy inside the following code :

```
var solc = require('solc');
var input = "contract x { function g() {} }";
var output = solc.compile(input, 1); // 1 activates the optimiser
for (var contractName in output.contracts) {
    // code and ABI that are needed by web3
    console.log(contractName + ': ' + output.contracts[contractName].bytecode);
    console.log(contractName + '; ' + JSON.parse( output.contracts[contractName].interface));
}
```

then run it using node test.js
you will get a result like  :

```
:x: 60606040523415600e57600080fd5b5b607d8061001d6000396000f300606060405263ffffffff7c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600035041663e2179b8e8114603c575b600080fd5b3415604657600080fd5b604c604e565b005b5b5600a165627a7a72305820ae6d537ab5d046202257892d26e5771413caeae62c0c9c574cf610f3e86179110029
:x; [object Object]
```